# How to vertically center cell content when its height is stretched by \arraystretch?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{5}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
Time & Monday \\\hline
16:00-16:30 &\\\hline
16:30-17:00 &\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to vertically center cell content when its height is stretched by `\arraystretch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\begin{document}

\begin{TAB}(r,1cm,2cm)[5pt]{|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}% (rows,min,max)[tabcolsep]{columns}{rows}
Time         & Monday \\
16:00--16:30 & f      \\
16:30--17:00 & f
\end{TAB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In lieu of `\arraystretch`, I add a homemade strut to the beginning of each row in column 1.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
%\renewcommand\arraystretch{5}
\def\mystrut{\rule[-6ex]{0ex}{14ex}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|!{\mystrut}c|c|}\hline
Time & Monday \\\hline
16:00-16:30 &\\\hline
16:30-17:00 &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To explain what is happening, `\mystrut` is just a zero width rule that stretches from 6ex below the baseline to 8ex above the baseline (a height of 14ex). By placing it among text, it creates a lot of room above and below the text.  I could manually add it to each row of the table, which is a little extra work.  To avoid that, I used the `!{}` facility of the `array` package to achieve the result (hat tip to David Carlisle).  This `!` feature executes the bracketed argument on every row of the tabular automatically (while retaining the `\tabcolsep`, unlike `@{}`).

Just to demonstrate what `\mystrut` looks like in this context, I below create a nearly identical macro, `\visiblestrut` defined as `{\rule[-6ex]{1ex}{14ex}}` so that it is 1ex wide (instead of 0), and manually place it before the word `Monday`.  Here is the result.  You can see that it is such a strut that creates the space above and below the actual text.

[image]

Comment: Please explain the mathematical aspect of your magic numbers.

Comment: @CodeMocker Explanation added.

Comment: Would be +1 f you replace `@{~` by `!{` (using `array` package. `!` is like `@` but doesn't remove tabcolsep space. As is you remove tabcolsep then add `~` which isn't the same length (normally).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thanks for the tip.  I didn't know how else to overcome that deficiency.  Let me work to fix it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found, in addition, that fragile commands don't need to be protected with `!`, unlike `@`.  Thanks again.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes more exactly fragile commands don't need to be protected with array package implementation (even if you use `@`)